# Get NSInvalidArgumentException when trying to present RPSystemBroadcastPickerView on iOS13 with Xcode11 beta4

Tags: xcode, xcode11, ios13, replaykit

When i trying to present RPSystemBroadcastPickerView in my app, i get an exception with the following description:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘NSInvalidArgumentException’, reason: ‘Application tried to present UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl to or from non-fullscreen view controller

I build my app with Xcode 11 beta 4 and the app runs on iOS13 beta 4. Fun fact, I do not get this exception if I run the app on iOS12 (built with Xcode 11 beta 4) and I present RPSystemBroadcastPickerView from a full-screen view controller. Why do I get this exception? Maybe I should wait for the final iOS13 version? Does anybody have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue on all the betas of iOS 13. I submitted a bug report using Apple's new Feedback website (https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/). To ensure that Apple fixes this before the official release of iOS 13, I would recommend that you also fill a bug report.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I have already reported this issue on Feedback Assistant.

Comment: Update: This issue is fixed in iOS 13.1 beta (17A5821e).

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative solution， you can build your app using XCode10, I test the app on the iOS 13 GM, it can work well. but if build app using xcode11, it will crash on the iOS 13 GM.

Comment: Yes, its a good workaround. FYI: With iOS13.1, your app will work perfectly with Xcode 11. I really do not know, why they did not fix this issue on iOS13.0 too.